# Strange Cuis quit behaviour

Tags: smalltalk

Experimenting with Cuis, i've found that:

If I evaluate separately, in a work space, the following statements, Smalltalks correctly saves it image and then it quits.

```
Smalltalk saveSession.
Smalltalk quitPrimitive.
```

However, If I select both statements and then I try to do them together, 
Smalltalks saves the image, but it does not quit.

The same thing happens if I try to do the following statement :

```
Smalltalk saveSession; quitPrimitive.
```

Any explanation ?

Comment: Not sure about Cuis, but most likely saveSession requires stopping the current process (it is hard to save the image while executing, you have to "freeze" things) and it could be that it does not restore that process to its current point after, assuming that it is safe to discard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resuming a Smalltalk image means to continue whatever it was doing when it was saved. "Saving" means taking a "snapshot" of the current object memory.

```
Smalltalk saveSession.
"<-- execution frozen here, this is what happens at startup"
Smalltalk quitPrimitive.
```

If you invoke save and quit in one expression, then it will snapshot first, and when starting up, execute the quit. If you do the snapshot separately, it will resume running the user interface on startup:

```
Smalltalk saveSession.
"<-- execution frozen here, nothing more happens at startup"
```

The second expression was not evaluated, so it is not "in the snapshot".

Basically Smalltalk starts up exactly where it left off - there is no `main` function as in other programming languages that is executed first. Smalltalk execution is simply "frozen" in the middle of the snapshot method, and when starting the image again, it is *still* in the snapshot method and just returns normally.

See `SystemDictionary>>snapshot:andQuit:embedded:`.

Startup happens in that method when the `snapshotPrimitive` returns. You can see that the startup list is processed after the snapshot, which will happen as the first thing when the image is "started".

Comment: So, what would be the reason for the second expression to not be evaluated? Is this a decision? I'm asking because it might also be the case that the second expression is executed twice, after #saveSession and at startup, which I think it would also make sense.

Comment: Leandro, I don't quite understand your question. If you evaluate the first expression (saveSession) and then the second (quitPrimitive) separately, then the second expression has no effect on the saved snapshot, because it was only selected for execution _after_ the snapshot was already created.

Comment: My question is why the decision was made to not evaluate the expression that follows #saveSession? A different decision, which I consider equally valid, would have been to save the session and keep the process running aftewards so that the second expression is evaluated too. Of course, it would be evaluated again on startup, but I don't see anything wrong with that. Do you?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. That's exactly how it works. The process is not stopped. The process keeps running. If you do `Smalltalk saveSession; quitPrimitive` then the quit is executed on startup _because_ the process is still running.

Comment: Ah, maybe now I understand your question: The reason for the second expression to not be evaluated is that it was not selected for the do-it before saving. That's what we mean by "evaluate separately": select first expression, do-it, select second expression, do-it.